# Прерогатива - этимология

Tags: этимология

Здравствуйте!
Задумался над словом "прерогатива" - "привилегия". Напрашивается вывод, что оно происходит от слова "рог". Или это вообще не русское слово?
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прерогатива - (лат., от prae - прежде, и rogare - испрашивать). Преимущество, исключительное право, исключительная привилегия. У римлян: центурия, подававшая прежде всех свой голос; в конституционных государствах: право монарха открывать и распускать парламент.

http://www.syl.ru/article/95573/prerogativa---eto-govoryaschaya-pervoy-istoriya-proishojdeniya-slova

Дословно «прерогатива» - это «говорящая первой». Именно так переводится слово с латыни. Его происхождение чрезвычайно интересно. В 6 веке до нашей эры царь Рима Сервий Туллий поделил граждан на 5 классов в соответствии с их благосостоянием. За пределами этого деления остались неимущие, пролетарии. Граждане каждого класса обязаны были выставить из своей среды определенное количество центурий для обороны Рима. Центурия – это 100 воинов. Вместе все классы выставляли 193 центурии.

Выбранные в центурии граждане собирались на собрания - центуриатские комиции. Сначала только для того, чтоб выбрать командира, но с течением времени центуриатские комиции стали собираться и для решения наиболее важных гражданских вопросов.

Голосование было организовано очень строго. Каждая центурия отходила в специально отведенный участок поля. По жребию определялся порядок, в котором центурии голосовали. «Прерогатива» - это название центурии, которой выпадало голосовать первой.